# Codeigniter active record - update query using data from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an array which itself contains two arrays - one holds `item ids` and the other holds the `order of the item`

They look something like this:

```
    Array
(
    [item_order] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [item_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 24
        )

)
```

What I now need to do is update each items row order based on its id

Not sure where to start with this one though.

The end result should look something like

```
item_id     item_name     item_order
------------------------------------
20          xxxxx         0
34          yyyyy         1
24          zzzzz         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform data into an `array` of `arrays`, containing `key` => `value` pairs(where keys are field names) and use [update_batch](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update) method of codeigniters active_record class:

```
list($item_id, $item_order) = $array_with_data; // or extract($array_with_data);

$data = [];

foreach($item_id as $i => $id) {
 $data[] = [ 'item_id' => $id, 'item_order' => $item_order[$i], ];
}

$this->db->update_batch('yourtable', $data, 'item_id');
```

What is going on in `foreach` loop

This:

```
Array
(
   [item_order] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
      )

    [item_id] => Array
      (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 34
        [2] => 24
      )

)
```

Is turned into this

```
Array
( 
  [0] => Array
  (
    'item_order' => 0
    'item_id' => 20
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    'item_order' => 1
    'item_id' => 34
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
    'item_order' => 2
    'item_id' => 24
  )
)
```

This is the format `update_batch` understand. Third parameter specifies a field which is used by function to know which row to update.

Update batch separates data by 100 rows and then creates case-based queries, thus avoiding large amount of queries.

Comment: I've slightly altered the array. Would this change your answer? What you're doing looks like what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your model by making function

```
$item_ids = $item['item_id'];
$orders = $item['item_order'];
if (!empty($item_ids) && !empty($orders)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_ids); $i++) {
        $data = array('item_order' => $orders[$i]);
        $this->db->where('item_id', $item_ids[$i]);
        $this->db->update('yourtablename', $data);
    }
}
```

[**Updating Data**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to loop and do a new update query for each row?

Comment: I guess no you have to loop over the array because you cannot arrange the ids in sequence to their order

Comment: @Tom see my answer, it does not use update in a cycle